# LoDash - How to push one collections values into another via common key

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, lodash

I have two collections.

```
var a = 
[
 {unique_id: "001", state: "CO"},
 {unique_id: "001", state: "TX"},
 {unique_id: "001", state: "CC"},
 {unique_id: "002", state: "CC"},
 {unique_id: "002", state: "NY"}
]
```

And

```
var b = 
[
 {unique_id: "001", states:[]},
 {unique_id: "002", states:[]}
]
```

And I want to get:

```
var b = 
[
 {unique_id: "001", states:["CO","TX","CC"]},
 {unique_id: "002", states:["CC","NY"]}
]
```

I should mention that the "b" array has to stay in the same order it's in AND some of the unique_id's don't have a value.

I've been trying to use LoDash https://lodash.com/ - so if anyone can solve this with LoDash that would be awesome!

Comment: What have you tried to do?  I'm not going to just tell you, though someone may!

Comment: I've tried _.forEach and _.forIn with Lodash, but can't seem to figure out how to match pushing the values into "b" by unique_id...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time complexity of this solution is suboptimal ( O(n^2) ), but it might help you think of ways to match pushing the values into "b":

```
_.forEach(a, function(element1){
  _.forEach(b, function(element2){
    if (element2.unique_id === element1.unique_id) {
     element2.states.push(element1.state);
    }
  });
});
```

Perhaps a better solution might be to index your objects in b by their unique id using lodash's **_.indexBy** method. For example you can index your objects in b as follows:

```
var c = _.indexBy(b, 'unique_id')
```

Which will result in:

```
{001:{unique_id: "001", states:[]}, 002: {unique_id: "002", states:[]}}
```

Since the objects in our c array are pointing to the same objects in memory as those in our b array, we can directly mutate our objects in c and b will reference those updated objects in memory. So:

```
_.forEach(a, function(element1){
  if (element1.unique_id in c) {
    c[element1.unique_id].states.push(element1.state);
  }
})
```

Now if we take a look at our b array, we'll see that the value is:

```
var b = 
[
 {unique_id: "001", states:["CO","TX","CC"]},
 {unique_id: "002", states:["CC","NY"]}
]
```

The time complexity of this solution should be close to O(n), which is much better than using the nested **_.forEach** approach. Code snippet:

```js
var a = 
[
 {unique_id: "001", state: "CO"},
 {unique_id: "001", state: "TX"},
 {unique_id: "001", state: "CC"},
 {unique_id: "002", state: "CC"},
 {unique_id: "002", state: "NY"}
];

var b = 
[
 {unique_id: "001", states:[]},
 {unique_id: "002", states:[]}
];

var c = _.indexBy(b, 'unique_id');

_.forEach(a, function(element1){
  if (element1.unique_id in c) {
    c[element1.unique_id].states.push(element1.state);
  }
});

document.writeln(JSON.stringify(b))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.9.3/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried _.indexBy and it sorts everything and I need the "b" array to stay in the same order it's in (it's complicated to explain)..

Comment: Hmm...I'm a bit confused. _.indexBy produces a new object and doesn't mutate the array it takes in. In my example "b" will retain it's original order.

Comment: Well... another thing I didn't mention is that some of the objects in "b" array have a null value for unique_id...

Comment: And you didn't specify that in your original post? Why?

Comment: @PavanRavipati - thanks!  The first option at the top (using foreach inside foreach) ended up being the best solution... Actually I used _.forEach, then _.forIn.  Using _.indexBy did re-index my original set and I think there were problems caused by some of the unique_id values being NaN...

Answer (score 2):

[groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) and [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) are your friends:

```
_(a).groupBy('unique_id')
    .map(function(item, key) {
        return {
            unique_id: key,
            states: _.pluck(item, 'state')
        };
    })
    .value()
```

You're basically grouping the states by their `unique_id`, then mapping that object to an array where each item has the structure you need.